# State change is not pushed to child component in React/Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm experiencing a strange problem where a state change in my Redux store reaches the parent component but not passed onto the child presentational component.

Simplified version of the code is this:

```
class MyParentComponent extends Component {

   render() {
      return(
         <div>
             <MyChildComponent files={this.props.selectedFiles} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    debugger; // I see that state change reaches here!
    return {
        id: ownProps.id,
        id2: ownProps.id2,
        selectedFiles: state.files.selectedFiles
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(myActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyParentComponent);
```

Notice the `debugger` I placed inside `mapStateToProps`. I confirm that I can see the state change where I have the `debugger` which means everything is working up to that point i.e. action creator, redux store, etc.

I also confirmed that my child component is indeed getting its data from `state.files.selectedFiles`. I manually placed some dummy data in the `selectedFiles` array in my `files` reducer and my component displayed it correctly.

As I mentioned, the state change is reaching the parent component but not the child component.

Any idea what may be happening here?

Comment: Can you please share a snippet of your child component?

Comment: OK! I figured this out. I was using a helper function to add an item into the `selectedFiles` array by simply doing this: `selectedFiles.push(newFile);`. I guess this was doing a shallow copy and the child component wasn't picking it up. I updated my helper function and added the new file into a new array using the spread operator and it started working.

Comment: You may want to add an official answer showing that issue and how you resolved it, this could potentially help someone in the future. Glad to hear you got it resolved!

Comment: I think the correct protocol is to close the question as offtopic because the solution is unrelated to the question.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to post a self answer. It's completely unacceptable to insult the community. If you see something you don't like, flag it. Don't resort to the sort of insults you are complaining against.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. Here's what was causing this issue:

As I was updating my `selectedFiles` array, I was using a helper function which simply pushed the new file into the array i.e. `selectedFiles.push(newFile);`.

Looks like this was performing a shallow copy and the child component wasn't picking it up.

I changed the helper function to return `[...selectedFiles, newFile];` and everything started to work fine.